# Windows 10 - extend "right click menu" in start menu (instead of having the "More" sub-menu)

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, gui, desktop-customization

Right click on an item in the Start menu shows the "More" sub-menu that has some functionalities inside.
How can I move these functionalities to the right click menu itself and remove the "More" sub-menu.

In other words, how to change:

[image]

To (illustration):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Holding shift then Right clicking?

Comment: Use a Start menu alternative such as [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/).

Comment: @NetworkKingPin, that doesn't work